# gridview column sum value, and display on webpage asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I currently have :

```
<asp:GridView ID="BalanceCheckDataGridView" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="30%" DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company" />
         <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="30%" DataField="Balance" HeaderText="Balance" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now I want to grab information from the balance, and sum them up, then display it ( can be at the end a row like "Total: sumValue" or a label where its text can be it's sum value)

I am new to this, Could you help please.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you do this in your sql query?

Comment: @briskovich: It would be better to do it just on my side, don't want to touch Database. Do you have any ideas please?

Comment: Do you want on the bottom of the grid?

Comment: @briskovich: that will be nice. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Int32 tot = 0; 
protected void Dg_Source_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        tot = tot + Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
        lblSum.Text = tot.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a footer on the grid and then you could do something like this in your code behind after your grid is bound.

```
((Label)your_grid.FooterRow.Cells[1].FindControl("your_label_to_diplay_total")).Text = "Total:" + ds.Tables[0].Compute("sum(your_balance_field)", "").ToString();
```

This is off the top of my head. You will have to customize it to your application.

Comment: thanks for the code, but i don't have a ds table, may i know what's that referrenced for?

Answer (score 0):

```
    int sum=0;
    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender,  GridViewRowEventArgs e)
         {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label salary = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label3");//take lable id
            sum +=int.Parse(salary.Text);
            lblsum.Text = sum.ToString();
        }
    }
```